# I am trying to use various transformations of the response variable and fit corresponding these model, and obtain residual plots for each model

Tags: r

```
library(GLMsData)
data(fluoro)
lambda <- seq(-2,2,0.5)
lm.out <- list()
for(i in length(lambda)){
  if(i != 0){
    y <- (fluoro$Dose^lambda-1)/lambda
  } else {
    y <- log(fluoro$Dose)
  }
  lm.out[[i]] <- lm(y[i]~Time, data = fluoro, na.exclude = T)
}
print(lm.out)
```

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = y[i] ~ Time, data = fluoro, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : variable lengths differ (found for 'Time')

I am trying to use various transformations of the response variable and fit these corresponding models, and obtain residual plots for each model.
I need a help.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a corrected version of the `for` loop in the question.

```
data(fluoro, package = "GLMsData")

lambda <- seq(-2, 2, 0.5)

lm.out <- list()
for(i in 1:length(lambda)){
  if(lambda[i] != 0){
    y <- (fluoro$Dose^lambda[i]-1)/lambda[i]
  } else {
    y <- log(fluoro$Dose)
  }
  lm.out[[i]] <- lm(y ~ Time, data = fluoro, na.action = na.exclude)
}
print(lm.out)
```

---

And a version with a `boxcox` function defined and used in a `lapply` loop.

```
boxcox <- function(x, lambda, na.rm = FALSE){
  if(na.rm) x <- x[!is.na(x)]
  if(lambda == 0){
    log(x)
  } else {
    (x^lambda - 1)/lambda
  }
}

lm_out2 <- lapply(lambda, \(l){
  lm(boxcox(Dose, lambda = l) ~ Time, data = fluoro, na.action = na.exclude)
})
```

---

Check that both ways above produce the same results.

```
coef_list <- sapply(lm.out, coef)
coef_list2 <- sapply(lm_out2, coef)
identical(coef_list, coef_list2)
#[1] TRUE

smry_list <- lapply(lm.out, summary)
smry_list2 <- lapply(lm_out2, summary)

pval_list <- sapply(smry_list, \(fit) fit$coefficients[, "Pr(>|t|)"])
pval_list2 <- sapply(smry_list2, \(fit) fit$coefficients[, "Pr(>|t|)"])
identical(pval_list, pval_list2)
#[1] TRUE

R2_list <- sapply(smry_list, "[[", "r.squared")
R2_list2 <- sapply(smry_list2, "[[", "r.squared")
identical(R2_list, R2_list2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Could you kindly explain the what ` \(l)` in your lapply function means does?

Comment: @Kwame `\(l)` is a lambda function, an anonymous function, introduced in R4.1.0. If you are running an older version of R, use the equivalent `function(l)` syntax. As for `l`, it stands for each element of the vector `lambda`.

Comment: that's pretty nice. Thanks for this education.

Comment: @Kwame I have now simplified the call to `lm` in the `lapply` loop. WIth argument `data = fluoro` there is no need to have `fluoro$Dose` in the formula (in the call to `boxcox`), I have removed the df name.

Comment: Alright, that's well noted. Thank you, Rui

Comment: @Kwame One more thing, you don't have to load a package to access its data sets, see the first instruction in my answer (just edited).

Comment: That's good to know from you. I appreciate that. Thanks